# How to convert from object to String?

Tags: java

How to convert arraylist selectitem  to string.I am getting as object.Please help me...

```
List<SelectItem> DtlLst = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
DtlLst.add(new SelectItem(DtlVO.getTrnId(),
                    DtlVO.getTrnId()));
---
---
String number =new String(DtlLst.get(0).toString());
                            System.out.println("number"+number.toString());
```

I  am getting as object.How to get this list first value ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried implementing the `toString` method of `SelectItem`?

Answer (score 1):

Preferrably override toString as @Jim has suggested.

Alternatively you could use [ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(YourObject)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString%28java.lang.Object%29) although there might be a performance penalty to pay since it is using reflection.